# CSS media queries kicking in without specified width

Tags: css, media-queries

I have one media query that kicks in without the width specified as a condition being met, even at 375px the media query takes over from the base CSS. The media query should take over from 660px. Here is my index.html page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Thames Accountants</title>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="header-bg">
   <header>
     <button id="toggleButton" class="c-hamburger c-hamburger--rot">
       <span>toggle menu</span>
     </button>
     <h1 class="logo">Thames Accountants</h1>
   </header>
   <p class="clear"></p>
   <div class="ta-menu">
    <nav>
      <ul>
         <li>Our Services</li>
         <li>About Us</li>
         <li>Blog</li>
         <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
     </div> <!-- end ta-menu div -->
     <div class="intro">
       <p>Personalised Accounting</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info ta-button">Get In Touch</button>
    <div><a href="#services"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down ta-icon"></span></a></div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- end header-bg div -->

  <div class="container">
  <a name="services"></a>
  <div id="services" class="services">
    <h2 class="services-title">Accountancy Services</h2>
    <p class="bullet-points">Annual Accounts <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Book-Keeping <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Company Secretarial <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Management Accounts <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="services">
    <h2 class="services-title">Added Value Services</h2>
    <p class="bullet-points">Business Valuations <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Business Plans <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Management Systems <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Strategic Planning <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="services">
    <h2 class="services-title">Start-up Services</h2>
    <p class="bullet-points">Ready made company <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Limited Liability Partnership <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">PLC formation <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="services">
    <h2 class="services-title">Taxation Services</h2>
    <p class="bullet-points">Contractors and IR35 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">Payroll, PAYE Returns and RTI <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
    <p class="bullet-points">VAT <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></p>
  </div> <!-- end services div -->
  </div> <!-- end container div -->
  <div class="testimonials">
    <h1 class="testimonial-title">Testimonials</h1>
     <div class="ta-container">
      <blockquote><p class="ta-review">Thames Accountants changes lives. Thanks for NOT being another overpaid below average bookkeeper but a true personalised accounting department for our company. - S. Johnson</p></blockquote>
      <blockquote><p class="ta-review">Thames Accountants changes lives. Thanks for NOT being another overpaid below average bookkeeper but a true personalised accounting department for our company. - S. Johnson</p></blockquote>
      <blockquote><p class="ta-review">Thames Accountants changes lives. Thanks for NOT being another overpaid below average bookkeeper but a true personalised accounting department for our company. - S. Johnson</p></blockquote>
    </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <div class="row ta-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 ta-about">
      <h4>About TA</h4>
      <p>We are an experienced accounting agency based in South East, London, UK. We work closely with our clients and act for a broad range of business and personal clients.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ta-social">
      <h4>Social</h4>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
      <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 ta-pages">
      <h4>Menu</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>Our Services</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div> <!-- end row div -->
   <div class="row ta-policies">
    <div class="ta-center">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul>
          <li>Privacy Policy</li>
          <li>Site terms</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </footer>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And this is my CSS media query

---

```
      Media queries for wider screens
      **********************************/

      @media (min-width: 660px)  { 
     /*Parallax image for home page*/
      .header-bg {
       background: radial-gradient(#252625, transparent 150%),   url('./img/tower-bridge.jpg');
       background-attachment: fixed;
       background-size: cover;
       background-position: center center;
       height: 600px;
       width: 100%;
       }

      .logo {
      font-size: 2em;
      margin: 3% 0 0 5%;
      text-align: left; 
      }

      .intro p {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      margin-top: 10%;
      }

      .ta-button {
      font-size: 0.6em;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      }

      .services-title {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      }

      .ta-menu {
      font-size: 1.5em;
      }

     .testimonial-title {
     font-size: 1.75em;
     }

      blockquote {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      border-left: 3px solid #fff;
      }

      .services p {
      font-size: 1em;
      }

      .ta-icon {
      margin-top: 0;
      }

      .c-hamburger {
      display: none;
      }

      .intro p {
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      border: none;
      } 

      }/*End media query @ 460 px*/
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your media query kicked in when less than 660 and not some other media query from other frameworks? I don't see how your media would kick in under 660

Comment: Have you tried this with a Fiddle or with an other "simulator"? Your code seems correct. Would need an overview of all of this to understand where the issue comes from. I would bet on an extra/missing `}` or something like that. You should try to validate (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) your CSS to see if any error pop out.

Comment: I've managed to fix the issue using <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">.